# Can't import PyQt5 on Raspberry Pi with Python 3.6.5

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, python-3.6

I am attempting to run a small PyQt application on a Raspberry Pi with jesse but cannot get the PyQt5 module to import in Python 3.6

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/debian_version
8.0

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools qttools5-dev-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
pyqt5-dev-tools is already the newest version.
qttools5-dev-tools is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jul  4 2019, 01:11:28)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
>>>
```

Is my import statement wrong?  Is the package named something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your import statement is not wrong. No, the (`apt` or `pip`) package is not named something else. However, Python 3.6.5 is not the [Python 3 version that shipped with Debian Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3) — that's Python 3.4.2.

Comment: Thanks John; you are correct I had installed Python 3.6.5.  I just discovered that running Thonny runs the native Python 3.4.2 and using that the import PyQt5 statement works just fine.  So I guess apt-get was still installing to 3.4 instead of 3.6?